ros2 colon build error in g++ 11.4 ubuntu 22.04
build code with ros2 and see this error
is there not install something?
or i make wrong in cmakelist?
i want create a socket with ros2 in ubuntu 22.04
$ colcon build
Starting >>> socket  
--- stderr: socket                             
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsocket: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/socket_server_node.dir/build.make:151: socket_server_node] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:165: CMakeFiles/socket_server_node.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2
---
Failed   <<< socket [0.22s, exited with code 2]


